# MVC5 Application context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, variables, asp.net-mvc-5, global-asax

I'm working with MVC5, I created "Site 1" and "Site 2" (application under IIS). "Site 2" is a sub-application of "Site 1". "Site 1" load "Site 2" through < iframe> tag.
In "Site 2" I set a **application variable** in Global.asax.

```
application["myvar"] = "value";
```

Can I read in "Site 1" the *application["myvar"]* variable of "Site 2"?

Comment: No. Of course not. They're two separate applications.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using two separate applications instead of MVC Areas?